# Discord Profil Picture Update from ElectronJS using request PATCH

Tags: node.js, api, electron, discord

I'm trying to code an application into Electron JS to allow the person to change their profile picture at the same time on several applications.
For this I use the APIs of each platform.
For Twitter it works correctly, but I block at the level of Discord.
I can make a GET request on the profile, but I can't do a : PATCH/users/@me
https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/user#modify-current-user

I do not know if it's the token that does not offer enough power, because I only asked for Identity as permission on my application.
I tried to pass JSON between true and false,
to add a content type, but I still have the same answer: {code: 0, message: '401: Unauthorized'}

```
function postDiscord(image) {
    const imageDataURI = require('image-data-uri')
    let {token} = store.get('discordToken') //get stored token

    imageDataURI.encodeFromFile(image)
    .then(res => {
        request({
            method: 'PATCH',
            url: 'https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me',
            headers: {
               'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token,
               'User-Agent': 'someBot (site, v0.1)'
            },
            body: {
                'avatar': res
            },
            json: true
            }, function(err, res) {
                if(err) {
                  console.error(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(res.body)
                }

            }
        );
    })
}
```

{code: 0, message: '401: Unauthorized'}

Answer (score 0):

Refering to Discord :https://github.com/discordapp/discord-api-docs/issues/1057
Cannot upload new pics with Oauth :/